# canon image runner 2420l on ubuntu

Tags: printing, canon

we are an Indian Government office and working on ubuntu. Recently we purchased canon image runner  2420 printer which was not able to connect to the system , since there is no driver . can anybody solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the printer driver for Linux from Canon
2. Extract it
3. change the directory to Debian 32bit
4. run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`